# How to get to play-through 1 after starting vault hunter mode?

Tags: borderlands-2

I have started playing through vault hunter mode (up to Sanctuary) in Borderlands 2, but I cannot access play-through 1. Whenever I press Continue from the main menu it just goes straight to play-through 2. Is there anyway to access play-through 1?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to go to Select Character from the main menu (you can't be in a game when you do this), then select the character you want to play Playthrough 1 with  (even if they're already "selected"). When you click them it will give you the option for "True Vault Hunter Mode" (playthrough 2/2.5) or Playthrough 1 ("Normal Mode", AFAIK). Just pick the first playthrough from that menu and hit Continue, you'll find yourself back in Playthrough 1 exactly how it ended, all of your old missions intact and enemies at level 30 max.

This is different from how Borderlands 1 worked for this, but it takes away one extra menu every time you try to play the game so that's probably why it was moved.

Comment: This is so non-obvious in game.  Thanks @BenBrocka.

Comment: Thank you so much! Was really beginning to get annoyed if I couldn't access everything we've already done! Wish they would have explained this better in the game!