# I've restarted the campaign by accident, can I cancel this?

Tags: pc, borderlands-2

Having finished Borderlands 2 core campaign I closed up for the night, when I restarted it presented me with the option to start in "True Vault Hunter Mode". I misclicked and now I'm right back at the start and my friends are all in Sanctuary laughing.

Is there a way to cancel this campaign restart?

Can I connect to my friends games and continue with the DLC as we planned?

Comment: when you start the game and are on the menu screen, there should be an option to play in normal or TVHM, you just need to switch it back.  It shouldn't be a problem to join your friends

Comment: What do you mean? You deleted your character or you're in playthrough 2 (with level 30+ enemies) and you want to get back to the first playthrough you completed?

Comment: @turbo There is? Excellent! I shall check.

Comment: @ben-brocka I'm on playthrough two, I believe, with level 30+ enemies.

Comment: I am almost positive there is, I haven't played in a couple months so I can't be more specific, but if you look through the menus it should be there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't actually restarted the campaign, you've started playthrough 2. However see [How to get to play-through 1 after starting vault hunter mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/86801/how-to-get-to-play-through-1-after-starting-vault-hunter-mode/86813#86813) for information on how to get back to playthrough 1. But you haven't lost anything and will probably want to play playthrough 2 with your buddies instead of continuing playthrough 1: see [How do subsequent playthroughs work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/85645/how-do-subsequent-playthroughs-work) Long story short, you'll only get better guns and a decent challenge at this point by playing playthrough 2.

Your current playthrough progress doesn't affect your ability to join friends games though; even if your friends are in a different playthrough or part of the story you can always join their game (the only risk is enemies may be impossible/crazy easy if your levels are mismatched). You can even hop into a DLC campaign you haven't started via a friend (only if you own the DLC of course)